# invalid keyword argument in django for course_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.11

I am trying to populate a models.table with data but I have an error

```
TypeError: 'course_id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

models.py

```
class Course(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    course_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True),
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u"title"), max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
```

example of data(dataframe ==)

```
Course Code title   
719176      lorem ipsu #1
719177      lorem ipsu #2
```

script

```
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    all_courses_ids = [l.course_id for l in Course.objects.all()]
    if( df1.iloc[i]['Course Code'] not in all_courses_ids):
        Course.objects.create(
        course_id=df1.iloc[i]['Course Code']
    )
```

Error

```
<ipython-input-2-0a2a41ded7eb> in <module>()
      3     if( df1.iloc[i]['Course Code'] not in all_courses_ids):
      4         Course.objects.create(
----> 5         course_id=df1.iloc[i]['Course Code']
      6     )
      7
...
...
TypeError: 'course_id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Try to remove comma after this line `course_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True),` and run makemigrations/migrate.

Comment: thanks @neverwalkaloner it works you can post this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typo in your code:

```
course_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True),
```

You should remove comma. Otherwise Python considers `course_id` as tuple, not as model's field.

Comment: keen observer ;)